# Html Newsletter link numerical values go blue in mobiles

Tags: html, css, media-queries, html-email, newsletter

I am coding email newsletter that is to be mobile compatible  , My problem is that when there is any numerical value or email address it becomes blue just as anchro tag , i ste it text-decoration:none; did set  its color:#33333;  but that still looks bad as in attached image [image]

Is it possible to change this blue color to black and make them without hyperlink?

Comment: You can try `color: #33333!important;` but without any code we really can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation : portrait){color:#333333 !important;
   text-decoration: none;}
```

Comment: that does not work  for iphne / ipad , i tested it using litmus.com

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you should do. Since it gets converted into an anchor tag, use that to your advantage:

```
<a style="text-decoration:none; color:#333333;">numerical value</a>
```

Using empty anchor tags like this won't make it into a clickable link on most mail clients, and will allow you to control the styling on clients that convert it to anchor tags, since that anchor style will be defined by you before hand.